# Capture the Conditional statement group by Count from case statement oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, conditional-statements, case

Hi I am trying to capture the counts by group but the group by i need is from the aritificial column from the case statement i was wondering how to acheive this , below is the sql code i am using is this possible using the WITH CTE ? or is there any simplest possible way , below is the query along with existing results and expected results

db - Oracle DB 11g

**QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
EA.TGT_TBL,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(EA.TGT_TBL, '[0-9]+') AS SYSTEM_ID,
COUNT(*),
ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) PERCENTAGE,
CASE WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE '%DWH_STAGE.%' THEN 'STAGE'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE '%DWH_STAGE_CST.%'THEN 'STAGE'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH.%' THEN 'STAGE'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_EDW.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_EDW.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_EDW_CST.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_EDW_CST.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_EDW_PREM2.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_EDW.%' THEN 'EDW'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_MART.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_MART.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_MART_CST.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_MART_CST.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'SHP_MART.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_REPO.%' THEN 'REPO'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_PMART.%' THEN 'MART'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_META.%' THEN 'META'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_META_CST.%' THEN 'META'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'DEV_DWH_META.%' THEN 'META'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'BI_DFL.%' THEN 'DFL'
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'MPN_ETL_WORK.%' THEN 'VISA'
ELSE 'OTHER'
    END AS SCHEMA_GROUP
FROM BI_ETL_AUD EA
WHERE 1=1
AND TRUNC(EA.SESS_BEG)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND TRUNC(EA.SESS_END)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY 
EA.TGT_TBL,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(EA.TGT_TBL, '[0-9]+')
ORDER BY 
EA.TGT_TBL,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(EA.TGT_TBL, '[0-9]+'),SYSTEM_ID,SCHEMA_GROUP
```

**EXISTING RESULTS**

```
TGT_TBL         SYSTEM_ID SCHEMA_GROUP COUNT(*) PERCENTAGE
AB_01_SHP_ORDER 01        STAGE        10       0.1
BC_AB_PUR_STTS  null      EDW          200      2
GH_FND_AJD_DAA  null      MART         10       0.1
SD_HS_HHA_DHD   null      REPO         100      1
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
SCHEMA_GROUP COUNT(*) PERCENTAGE
STAGE        500      10
EDW          1500     30
MART         3000     60
REPO         250      05
```

Please note that i am trying to get the group by from SCHEMA_GROUP (this column is not in the table - Artificial column used in the CASE statement)

Comment: User a subquery or CTE so you can refer to the alias.

Comment: i tried using with cte but this artificial column SCHEMA_GROUP i was not able to place ORA-00904: "SCHEMA_GROUP": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 86 Column: 8

Comment: You typically **do not** use `DISTINCT` in combination with `GROUP BY` in one query. What do you try to eliminate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach with CTE for your setup (with a bit limited `case`)

```
with ea as (
select 
CASE WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE '%DWH_STAGE.%' THEN 'STAGE'
-- cur for brevity
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'MPN_ETL_WORK.%' THEN 'VISA'
ELSE 'OTHER'
    END AS SCHEMA_GROUP
FROM BI_ETL_AUD EA)
select 
  SCHEMA_GROUP,
  COUNT(*),
  ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) PERCENTAGE
from ea
group by SCHEMA_GROUP;
```

This produces

```
SCHEM   COUNT(*) PERCENTAGE
----- ---------- ----------
OTHER          3         75
VISA           1         25
```

with sample data

```
create table BI_ETL_AUD as
select 'DEV_DWH_EDW.'  TGT_TBL from dual union all
select 'DEV_DWH_EDW.'  TGT_TBL from dual union all
select 'DEV_DWH_EDW.'  TGT_TBL from dual union all
select 'MPN_ETL_WORK.'  TGT_TBL from dual
```

Alternatively you can always use a single query, you need to copy the case *exact and without alias* in the `GROUP BY` columns:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE '%DWH_STAGE.%' THEN 'STAGE'
  -- cur for brevity
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'MPN_ETL_WORK.%' THEN 'VISA'
  ELSE 'OTHER'
    END AS SCHEMA_GROUP,
  COUNT(*),
  ROUND(100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) PERCENTAGE    
FROM BI_ETL_AUD EA
group by CASE WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE '%DWH_STAGE.%' THEN 'STAGE'
-- cur for brevity
     WHEN EA.TGT_TBL LIKE 'MPN_ETL_WORK.%' THEN 'VISA'
ELSE 'OTHER'
    END
```

Comment: Many thanks 2nd query is much effective , fantastic it works

Comment: Well basically both queries should have the same performance. You will find the *drawback of the second approach* if you have to frequently update the `CASE` statement and you forgot to do the same change in the `group by`;)